# memoir class: Why does MakeUppercase break my cftpartfont?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, capitalization

According to [page 151 of the memoir class documentation](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf), if one wishes to uppercase the PART entries in the ToC, then one should use e.g.

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\MakeUppercase}
```

Yet when I try even this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\MakeUppercase}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{This is a part.}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX complains, "./.toc.1: Argument of \partnumberline has an extra }." Huh??

Comment: Delete your `.toc` file and compile again. Did that work?

Comment: No. :( Does that mwe compile for you? Maybe LaTeX just hates me.

Comment: Yes, it does here. :-)

Comment: Fails for me using `memoir` 3.6j, dated 2011/03/06. I'm betting it's fixed in later versions. [The changelog](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/README) shows some uppercase-related fixes in 3.7.

Comment: Exactly which memoir version are you using?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an out of date class file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are reading manuals online, you of course make sure that the version you are using matches that manual. In this case it does not.

Use an updated LaTeX installation.

Comment: Haha, sounds good. <thumbs up>